# How to run songs playlist at the startup

Tags: 14.04, startup, rhythmbox, playlists

**Hello, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

*Can Anyone show me how to automatically play a playlist at the startup of the system, but I want it with 4 seconds sleep, so the system can load perfectly*

**PS : I want the playlist to be played on Rhythmbox**

**Thank You**